# Change text with flipping animation on hover Jquery/css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change some text on hover with a flipping animation.
The number "1" would be displayed and on hover the number flip horizontally to become a "0".
When the hover out, the number would return to "1"

I can't success to make it fluid.

Any help, script which you do it?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE : https://jsfiddle.net/4t7ogtfz/

Here's what I try.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("p").hover(function(){
    $("p").text('0');
    });
</script>
```

```css
p{
    font-size:45px;
    display:inline-block;
}

p:hover{
    transition: all ease-in 1s 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s 0s;
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(180deg);
    transform: rotatex(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make backface visibility hidden, use two elements instead of one, position:absolute them on top of eachother, put them in a containing element - when the containing element is hovered, trigger your flip transition.

Read this:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip